# How to merge regex group matches?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the line below:

```
one two three
```

Is it possible to write a regex that would return below?

```
one three
```

I can of course get each part in a separate group but is it possible to capture that in a single match?

Comment: A single match, yes (as in, a single pattern), but you would still need two groups. Generally speaking, capture groups capture contiguous parts of the string - since `one` and `three` are NOT contiguous, you would need two capture groups.

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if there's some regex magic that would merge them in one group.

Comment: You have to do it in code, outside of your regex. Something like (in Perl, for instance) `$string =~ /(one) two (three)/; print "$1 $2";`.

Comment: There is no regex engine that matches discontinuous texts, you can do that in code. A regex replace operation with capture groups and backreferences will do the job.

Comment: I can't do it in code, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it simply: no, it can't be done (as discussed in comments on your original question).

To find out why, let's look at it a bit more generally. A regular expression can be modelled as a (often complex) [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), also known as a DFA, and your average regex engine is implemented as one. What this means is that the regex will slurp zero or one character at a time, and see if it matches the current token. If not, it will backtrack and attempt to match any possible token at the current stage (done with the alternation operation `|`). If unable, it halts and reports it cannot match. Since a DFA operates on the input in sequential order, what you're asking for is basically impossible by definition.