# Regex capture into group everything from string except part of string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create a regex, which will capture everything from a string, except for specific parts of the string. The he best place to start seems to be using groups.

For example, I want to capture everything except for "production" and "public" from a string.
Sample input:

> california-public-local-card-production
>
> production-nevada-public

Would give output

> california-local-card
>
> nevada

On https://regex101.com/ I can extract the strings I don't want with

```
(production|public)\g
```

But how to capture the things I want instead?
The following will kind of get me the word from between production and public, but not anything before or after https://regex101.com/r/f5xLLr/2 :

```
(production|public)-?(\w*)\g
```

Flipping it and going for \s\S actually gives me what I need in two separate subgroups (group2 in both matches) https://regex101.com/r/ItlXk5/1 :

```
(([\s\S]*?)(production|public))\g
```

But how to combine the results? Ideally I would like to extract them as a separate named group , this is where I've gotten to https://regex101.com/r/scWxh5/1 :

```
(([\s\S]*?)(production|public))(?P<app>\2)\g
```

But this breaks the group2 matchings and gets me empty strings. What else should I try?

Edit: This question boils down to this: [How to merge regex group matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788301/how-to-merge-regex-group-matches)
Which seems to be impossible to solve in regex.

Comment: What is your language / environment?

Comment: You could split/apply/combine.

Comment: I think it is not clear what you want to obtain, the specific tool(s) you are using and what is not allowed do to.

Answer (score 1):

A regexp match is always a **continuous** range of the sample string. Thus, the anwswer is "No, you cannot write a regexp which matches a series of concatenated substrings as described in the question".

But, this popular kind of task is being solved very easily by replacing unnecessary words by empty strings. Like

```
s/-production|production-|-public|public-//g
```

(Or an equivalent in a language you're using)

Note. Provided that `\b` is supported, it would be more correct to spell it as
    s/-production\b|\bproduction-|-public\b|\bpublic-//g

(to avoid matching words like 'subproduction' or 'publication')

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is nearly there:

```
([\s\S]*?)(?>production|public)
```

But this results in multiple matches

```
Match 1
Full match  0-17    `california-public`
Group 1.    0-11    `california-`

Match 2
Full match  17-39   `-local-card-production`
Group 1.    17-29   `-local-card-`
```

So You have to match multiple times to retrieve the result.