# Regex to capture 1 character, skip 2 and capture the rest appending it to the first character captured

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble trying to capture what i need.
So the string I'm trying to capture from, looks like this:

```
Managed client:ASB3200418
```

And I need to capture the A after the colon, followed by the digits (so ignore the SB). So essentially I need to capture this:
A3200418

I've tried a couple of combinations which I thought should work, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what i've tried:

1. `(?:Managed\s*client:)A(?:SB)\w*`
2. `(?:Managed\s*client:)A.{2}\K[A-Z]*\w*`

Any other suggestions of how to capture what i need much appreciated.
Cheers
mark.

Comment: I'm not sure what language you are using, but from a Python standpoint, couldn't you do something like this? `re.search(r'Managed client:A(?:SB)(\d+)', s)`. You might need to cheat a bit an prepend an 'A' but I think the rest would work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788301/how-to-merge-regex-group-matches

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 capturing groups, capture a single char A-Z in group 1 and capture 1 or more digits in group 2.

```
\bManaged\s+client:([A-Z])[^\d\s]*(\d+)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bManaged\s+client:` Match `Managed client:` with a leading word boundary and 1+ whitespace chars in between
- `([A-Z])` Capture group 1, match a single char A-Z
- `[^\d\s]*` Match optional chars other than and digit or a whitespace char
- `(\d+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Be7PCG/1)

Or the more specific:

```
\bManaged\s+client:(A)SB(\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0JEpQY/1)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than capturing what you want you could replace what you don't want with empty strings, using the regular expression.

```
^.*:|(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOzP41/1)

This expression reads, "Match all characters from the beginning of the string (`^`) up to and including the last colon or (`|`) match an uppercase letter `[A-Z]` that is preceded by an uppercase letter." `(?<=[A-Z])` is a *positive lookbehind*. It's an assertion that must be satisfied but is not part of the match that is returned.

One may also hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 0):

You just capture two things and put both of them in the replace string.  In javascript, for example, you can do this:

```
let line="Managed client:ASB3200418";
console.log(line.replace(/Managed client:(\w)..(\w+)/,"$1$2"));
```

Output:

```
A3200418
```